# Discord.Js Problem adding a space after a +

Tags: discord.js

ok so ik this is preety rookie but can someone help me out here. How do i add spaces in between +'s in code. `message.channel.send("you baked" + random + "Cookies! :3 :cookie:")
  }` It outputs BakedCookies all together due to the +'s

Comment: Don't forget to upvote or mark question as `answered` if someone helps you with your case. You could also find more info about string notations at MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `+ " " +` to add spaces for these cases. However, I would prefer using Template strings like this:

```js
message.channel.send(`You baked ${random} cookies! :3 :cookie`)
```

which would not require so many + and " ".

If your project is really slow though, using template literals actually slow speeds. Not by a lot but its something to note

Answer (score 1):

If you had three variables and needed spaces between them, you'd do:

```js
message.channel.send(num1 + " " + num2 + " " + num3);
```

In your case, you're already using string literals, so you can just do:

```js
message.channel.send("you baked " + random + " Cookies! :3 :cookie:");
```

Although, as Alex already mentioned, you can use `${random}` in your string with Javascript. To do that, you can do this:

```
message.channel.send(`you baked ${random} Cookies! :3 :cookie:`);
```

Comment: Tysm for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
message.channel.send(`you baked ${random} Cookies! :3 :cookie:`)
```